# When to use collect and collectLatest operator to collect kotlin flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I want to know a practical scenario of both of them. I know the difference but couldn't relate to my implementation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 74):

Collect will collect every value , and CollectLatest will stop current work to collect latest value,

`The crucial difference from collect is that when the original flow emits a new value then the action block for the previous value is cancelled.`

```
flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(50)
    emit(2)
}.collect { value ->
    println("Collecting $value")
    delay(100) // Emulate work
    println("$value collected")
}
```

`prints "Collecting 1, 1 collected, Collecting 2, 2 collected"`

```
flow {
    emit(1)
    delay(50)
    emit(2)
}.collectLatest { value ->
    println("Collecting $value")
    delay(100) // Emulate work
    println("$value collected")
}
```

`prints "Collecting 1, Collecting 2, 2 collected"`

So , if every update is important like state, view, preferences updates, etc , collect should be used .
And if some updates can be overridden with no loss , like database updates , collectLatest should be used.

Comment: What is the `delay` represents here? Is it a network call or a database access?

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS, can be, it represents something which takes some time to compute/access

Comment: what about `.conflate()` + collect{}, does it do the same or different?

Answer (score 3):

i think this [article](https://hardiksachan.com/kotlin-flows-collect-vs-collectlatest) made it simple with example.

The tradeoff between **collect { ... }** and **collectLatest { ... }** is simple.
when you need to process all the values you receive, you should use *collect*, and when you want only the **latest** value to be processed, use *collectLatest*.

Answer (score 0):

Before talking about what `collect` and `collectLastest` can do for us, let's recall what the goal of a flow is. A flow does, long story short, the same as what a suspend function does, except that it does that for multiple values. So when we want to return multiple values we return a flow of values instead of one single value via a suspend function.

Both collect functions do something different. They process all emitted values and return nothing.

When `collect` gets called, all emitted values will be processed. So for example, when collecting realtime data of the temperature in a room, we may want to process all of this data sequentially.

Considering function:

```
private suspend fun processTemperature(value: Int) {
    println("Processing-> $value")
    delay(Random.nextLong(1, 5))
    println("Processed!-> $value")

}
```

For this we can use `collect` like this:

```
flow {
    repeat(10) {
        emit(Random.nextInt(10, 25))
        delay(2)
    }
}.collect { value ->
   processTemperature(value)
}
println("Finished processing collect!")
```

This will process all values and this is interesting for example if we want to keep a full history of all temperatures and calculations. However if for example the system fails or starts failing, we just want to process a temperature if processing is under 2 milliseconds. For this we can use `collectLatest`. Because a new action block cancels any running collect block, we can guarantee that `collectLatest` will get to process only temperatures that take less than 2 milliseconds to process:

```
flow {
    repeat(10) {
        emit(Random.nextInt(10, 25))
        delay(2)
    }
}.collectLatest { value ->
    processTemperature(value)
}
println("Finished processing collectLatest!")
```

`collectLast` isn't about collecting the last emitted value. It is more about cancelling the current action block when a value is emitted and that value is what is meant by last which can be useful in our example. And the reason is of course, and with other words, to keep the reading pace timed equally regardless of what happens during collection.

I would not expect a lot of use cases for `collectLast` in general but for more scientific things like this example they can be very usefull.

Find more here:

1. [Flows in Android](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow)
2. [collectLast in KotlinLang](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect-latest.html)
3. [collect in KotlinLang](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect.html)

You can find the original code on my example [here](https://github.com/jesperancinha/jeorg-kotlin-test-drives/blob/main/jeorg-kotlin-coroutines/coroutines-crums-group-1/src/main/kotlin/org/jesperancinha/ktd/TicketCollectors.kt)